# Perl is changing and eliminating declared variables when parsing and printing segments of file? Possible bug?

Tags: linux, perl

I am trying to parse a file using Perl (v5.10.1 built for x86_64-linux) and the file has blocks of information of three lines like this:

```
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5,Header6,Header7,Header8,Header9
Slot11,Slot12,Slot13,Slot14,Slot15,Slot16,Slot17,Slot18,Slot19
Slot21,
Slot31,
Slot11,Slot12,Slot13,Slot14,Slot15,Slot16,Slot17,Slot18,Slot19
Slot21,
Slot31,
Slot11,Slot12,Slot13,Slot14,Slot15,Slot16,Slot17,Slot18,Slot19
Slot21,
Slot31,
and so on....
```

Now, I have Perl script that loads the file line per line

```
my @lines; 
while (<$INPUT>) {
    chomp;
    push @lines, $_;
}
```

And then I process it...

```
for (my $i = 1; $i <= $#lines; $i+=3) { ###skip the header line
    chomp $lines[$i];
    my @line = split (/\,/, $lines[$i]);
    my $cl1 = $line[6]; #Load Slot17
    my $cl2 = $line[7]; #Load Slot18
    my $ref1 = $lines[$i + 1]; #Load Slot21
    my $ref2 = $lines[$i + 2]; #Load Slot31
    chomp $ref1;
    chomp $ref2;
    chomp $cl1;
    chomp $cl2;
    #######Beware, problematic line!!!!!!!!
    print "$cl1\t$cl2\t$ref1\t$ref2\n";
```

}

Each time I run this script the output is completely different to what I expected.

```
    Slot17     Slot31     Slot21
```

If I change the problematic line with:

```
    print "$cl1\n$cl2\n$ref1\n$ref2\n";
```

The results is as expected, that is:

```
    Slot17
    Slot18
    Slot21
    Slot31
```

I also debugged the script and print variable by variable just before the problematic line and everything is fine. The problem seems to be in the print line, but I'm totally puzzled about what is causing it. Furthermore, this is a very simple script, there isn't that much space for unnoticed mistakes. How and why is my computer changing positions and eliminating results in my output? What causes this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your file contains carriage return characters.

Eliminate them with `s/\r//;` in your input loop.

If you have a problem where a variable's value doesn't seem to be quite what you expect, you can make non-printable characters obvious by doing:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;
print Dumper $variable;
```

Comment: Please add

`$Data::Dumper::Useperl = 1;`

as modern Data::Dumper uses XS and simple hack won't work

Comment: @Demiurg what simple hack?

Comment: `$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;`

Comment: @Demiurg how is that a "hack"?  It says to dump strings double-quoted and show non-space whitespace or non-printable characters as escape sequences, which is exactly what I want.  Whether the XS or perl backend is used is irrelevant.

Can you explain better why I should add Useperl?

Answer (score 0):

And array elements counting from 0, not 1. So  $line[7] is Slot18, not Slot17.

Comment: That is true, but not helpful to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with varying line terminators on different platforms is best solved by using the `\R` regex expression which matches any single vertical whitespace character (including `LF` and `CR`) as well as the CR LF pair that is found in Windows and on the internet

Replacing `chomp` with `s/\R\z//` will remove the line terminator from any file, regardless of its source